# How to support subdomain wildcard in Ocelot (E.g. *.mydomain.com)

Tags: identityserver4, .net-core-3.0, ocelot

Here is my environment:

1. Multitenant with subdomain (e.g. t01.app.com) as the tenant identification strategy.
2. Using IdentityServer4 for issuing token. Each tenant will have his own issuer. E.g. t01.app.com is the issuer for t01.
3. Using Ocelot as the gateway

I am hoping to achieve such that the Ocelot is able to redirect with subdomain as a wildcard

- Browser A invokes t01.ocelot.com -> Ocelot redirects to t01.app.com
- Browser B invokes t02.ocelot.com -> Ocelot redirects to t02.app.com

Anyone can help me out? Or suggest some other gateway which can support this.